# NSString to parameter of type UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Hi I came along this problem can someone solve this for me?

```
unichar aChar7 = [textview.text characterAtIndex:0];

if (aChar7 == 'A' ){
    [imageview7 setImage: @"BLUEBOXA.png"];
```

It says

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'UIImage *'

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the UIImageView "setImage" takes a UIImage type as the parameter. So you need to make a UIImage instance first. Do this:

```
myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BLUEBOXA.png"];
[imageview7 setImage: myImage];
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

The parameter to `setImage` is an `UIImage`, not `NSString.` Try this:

```
[imageview7 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BLUEBOXA.png"]];
```

Comment: Ah yeah thanks I knew it was simple just didn't know it Thanks!!

Comment: No errors anymore, this code is in my viewDidLoad by the way, when I run it, it crashes and says: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'

Comment: I suspect that your textview is empty, so `characterAtIndex:0` is throwing exception. You can test the length of `textview.text` and read index zero only if there is something at index zero.

Answer (score 1):

1 - The following statement will look the name of the file. If this is the first time the image is being loaded, the method looks for an image with the specified name in the application’s main bundle.

```
UIImage *blueBoxImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BLUEBOXA"]; 
//see my 3rd point, no need to specify png format
```

2 - if blueBoxImage returns nil; the method could not find the specified image.

Because this method looks in the **system caches** for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method loads the image data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns the resulting object.

3 - On iOS 4 and later, **if the file is in PNG format, it is not necessary to specify the .PNG filename extension**. Prior to iOS 4, you must specify the filename extension.

Now, once you are ready with your photo, you can frame it :). I mean once got that image object, you are ready to set to your UIImageView

```
imageView7.image = blueBoxImage;
```